# Why does WFI instruction on STM32U585 immediately exit?

Tags: stm32

I have a STM32U585 on a custom board with code started from CubeMX using ThreadX.

I can send commands through a command line interface.  The command to put the processor into STOP2 mode works but the command to put the processor into SLEEP mode immediately returns.  The code is supposed to wait at the WFI instruction until the RTC module clears a flag in the ISR or until the EXTI ISR clears a different flag.

FYI:  There is a bunch of diagnostic code in the below fragment of the SLEEP mode function that doesn't work.

```
   rtc_callback_was_active = false;
   hall_callback_was_active = false;

   /*   ENTER SLEEP MODE */
   LP_ModeActivated   = true;
   STOP_ModeActivated = false;

   //HAL_SuspendTick();
   HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT( &htim15 );

   sleepProblem = 0;
   while( !rtc_callback_was_active && !hall_callback_was_active )
   {
       dbgReg = DBGMCU->CR;

       for( int i = 0; i < 125; i++ )
       {
           if( HAL_NVIC_GetActive( i ) )
           {
               irqsActive_before[i]++;
           }

           if( HAL_NVIC_GetPendingIRQ( i ) )
           {
               irqsPending_before[i]++;
           }
       }

       DBGMCU->CR = 0;
       __DSB(); // data sync barrier

       HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI); //first param unused in HAL function

       DBGMCU->CR = dbgReg;
       sleepProblem++;

       for( int i = 0; i < 125; i++ )
       {
           if( HAL_NVIC_GetActive( i ) )
           {
               irqsActive_after[i]++;
           }

           if( HAL_NVIC_GetPendingIRQ( i ) )
           {
               irqsPending_after[i]++;
           }
       }

   }

    //HAL_ResumeTick();
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT( &htim15 );
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM15_IRQn);

    if( sleepProblem > 9 )
    {
        SC_Printf( "Did not actually sleep issue (tried %d times) at line %d in %s\r\n",
                    sleepProblem, __LINE__, __FILE__ );
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 125; i++ )
    {
        if( irqsActive_before[i] != 0 )
        {
            foundOne++;
        }

        if( irqsPending_before[i] != 0 )
        {
            foundOne++;
        }

        if( irqsActive_after[i] != 0 )
        {
            foundOne++;
        }

        if( irqsPending_after[i] != 0 )
        {
            foundOne++;
        }
    }

    if( foundOne )
    {
        SC_Printf( "found %d unexpected interrupt(s)\r\n", foundOne );
    }
```

When the code is run I get the following on the serial port:

> >sys slp 1 10

> EM1 sleep for 10s

> Did not actually sleep issue (tried 1097 times) at line 348 in ../Core/Src/syscommands.c
> >

Note that the "unexpected interrupts" line is not run so no active or pending interrupts were present.

TIM15 is used to generate the system's 1 ms timer.  SysTick is not used.

The call to clear DBGMCU->CR disables the SWD/JTAG interface so the debugger shouldn't be waking the system up.

The code below is from the STOP2 mode function that does work (and it also has some diag code in it)

```
    LP_ModeActivated   = false;
    STOP_ModeActivated = true;


    //HAL_SuspendTick();
    HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT( &htim15 );
    sleepProblem = 0;
    while( !rtc_callback_was_active && !hall_callback_was_active )
    {
        dbgReg = DBGMCU->CR;

        __DSB();    // data sync barrier
        DBGMCU->CR = 0;

        PWR_EnterSTOP2Mode(0, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI); //first param unused in HAL function

        DBGMCU->CR = dbgReg;

        sleepProblem++;
    }

    //HAL_ResumeTick();
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT( &htim15 );
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM15_IRQn);

    if( sleepProblem > 9 )
    {
        SC_Printf( "Did not actually sleep issue (tried %d times) at line %d in %s\r\n",
                    sleepProblem, __LINE__, __FILE__ );
    }
```

> >sys slp 2 10

> EM2 stop for 10s

> >

Note that the error message is not displayed and the code did pause for about 10 seconds.

Any suggestions?  I cannot figure out what is causing the WFI to be interrupted when I call the SLEEP routine.

Comment: something is interrupting it.  For example interrupt or even not cleared pending bit. WFI works fine unless you do something wrong. I would strongly suggest not to trust HAL only write it low level

Comment: As @0___________ suggests, do you get the same result if you just `__WFI()` rather than calling `HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode()` ?

Comment: Note:
  I changed the code to remove the HAL library call but it still doesn't work.

```

    sleepProblem = 0;
    while( !rtc_callback_was_active && !hall_callback_was_active )
    {
        dbgReg = DBGMCU->CR;
        DBGMCU->CR = 0;
   
        /* Clear SLEEPDEEP bit of Cortex System Control Register */
        CLEAR_BIT(SCB->SCR, ((uint32_t)SCB_SCR_SLEEPDEEP_Msk));
        __DSB();
        __WFI();

        DBGMCU->CR = dbgReg;
        sleepProblem++;
    }
```